# Obtaining key by sending value (HashMap) through GET Method with @GetMapping

Tags: java, json, spring, hashmap

[Compass itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnt4S.png), [For Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcxuF.png) Creating simple compass by Spring, where in HashMap: keys are directions (N,W,S,E) and values are degrees (0-360) - how to get key in response by sending value? Is it possible to get key through value? (@GetMapping, JSON). When I'm run Postman for direction (JSON / "direction" : "W") - it is works fine, and response by range of degrees for West, but how to use range of degrees (values in my HashMap) to get in response direction (keys in my HashMap - "W", for example). If anyone can explain, even without code examples for I can understand which way to search.

Code for Compass itself:

```
public class CompassModel implements Serializable {

private static final CompassModel instance = new CompassModel();

private final Map<String, Compass> compassModel;

public CompassModel() {
    compassModel = new HashMap<String, Compass>();

    compassModel.put("North", new Compass("337-359, 0-21"));
    compassModel.put("North-East", new Compass("22-66"));
    compassModel.put("East", new Compass("67-111"));
    compassModel.put("East-South", new Compass("112-156"));
    compassModel.put("South", new Compass("157-201"));
    compassModel.put("South-West", new Compass("202-246"));
    compassModel.put("West", new Compass("247-291"));
    compassModel.put("West-North", new Compass("292-336"));
}

public static CompassModel getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public Compass getCompass(String arrow) {
    return compassModel.get(arrow);
}

public Map<String, Compass> getAllCompass() {
    return compassModel;
}
```

}

Code for Controller:

private static final CompassModel compass = CompassModel.getInstance();

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getCompass", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Compass getCompass(@RequestBody Map<String, String> compassArrow) {
    return compass.getCompass(compassArrow.get("direction"));
}

@GetMapping(value = "/getAllCompass", produces = "application/json")
public Map<String, Compass> getAllCompass() {
    return compass.getAllCompass();
}
```

Comment: add what you have tried in your code, what is the current output ad how you want it. That will help us to help you

Comment: I want to send JSON ("direction" : 90) and get response from localhos ("E"), for example. It is work for ("direction" : "E") - response is (90) because key - "E", value - 90. I need to work it reverse by sending value, not key. Sorry if complicated - not good at English.

Comment: please add code, not images

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to input the range values like[from your question] `337-359, 0-21`  or `22-66` and want the response of the keys `North` and
`North-East` respectively.
For that, you can try this way[I know this is not a good solution, but it should work]

```
compassModel.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .filter(entry -> Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), your_hashmap_value))
              .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

`your_hashmap_value` this is the hashmap value you get from your request.

Let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Trying to to add code in Controller - entrySet() from compass.entrySet() is highlighted by red (IDE request to create the mrthod, but I understand that entrySet() is a standart and must be by default). So, I use the code for Compass itself by compassModel.entrySet()... - Postman responsed by 500 error. I am a novice (nearly month of learning Java) and believe that you give me right solution. Just need to find out how to implement it properly. Thank you for helping!

Comment: @rrg, my bad!  The entryset is for the hashmap. It was a type. I have updated the answer, please check now